# Unable to edit S3 object metadata in console or Cyber Duck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to edit the metadata for S3 objects in both Cyber Duck and the AWS Console. Cyber Duck does not give me an error, but does not apply the settings. When I try to edit the data in the AWS Console I get the following error message:

```
Sorry! You were denied access to do that.
```

I can upload and do everything else in the bucket, and I have the AmazonS3FullAccess policy applied to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The files were uploaded as an anonymous user, therefor I could not edit anything about them. I re-uploaded everything with correct credentials and was able to change the metadata.